# Como passar um string como parâmetro na Action

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Preciso passar como parâmetro uma string onde ele retorna todos os itens que tem o mesmo nome.
Aqui ele está retornando Null.

Com o Id ele funciona perfeitamente.

```
[HttpGet, ActionName("Search")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Search([FromQuery] string hosts)
{
    if (hosts == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }
    return View(_context.Histories.Where(x => x.Host == hosts).ToList());
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você precisa definir de onde vem este valor.

No caso de uma requisição GET, ele pode vir da rota:

```
[HttpGet("{hosts}"), ActionName("Search")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Search([FromRoute] string hosts)
{
    ...
}
```

Neste caso a chamada seria: **`http://url-base/Search/valor-hosts`**.

Ou você pode recebê-lo via querystring

```
[HttpGet, ActionName("Search")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Search([FromQuery] string hosts)
{
    ...
}
```

A chamada seria: **`http://url-base/Search?hosts=valor-hosts`**.

Também é possível receber um valor de um *header*, mas duvido que isso seja útil agora.

---

De acordo com seu comentário, o problema mesmo está na montagem da *view*. Segue um exemplo de como fazer.

```
@{
    var querystringValues = new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
        { "hosts", "teste-teste" }
    };
}

<a asp-controller="Histories" asp-action="Search"
   asp-all-route-data="querystringValues">Clique aqui</a>
```

Comment: Olá, ele continua retornando Null, estranho..

Comment: @Matheusls Como você está chamando a rota?

Comment: <a asp-controller="Histories" asp-action="Search" asp-route-id="@item.Host" >, isso é como eu chamo na View.

Comment: Não faz sentido usar `asp-route-id` pra mandar uma querystring. Dê uma olhada [na documentação](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/built-in/anchor-tag-helper?view=aspnetcore-3.1)

Comment: @Matheusls De qualquer forma, isso não é um problema no controller e sim na view. Você deveria ter especificado isso na pergunta (junto com o código da view).

Comment: Funcionou, obrigada pela ajuda e desculpa pela falta de atenção =p